# How to Get the values from a Dictionary Column and add it to the column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[This my dataframe and I am trying to get the winningTrans to be incuded with the dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFngh.png)

Cannot include image as reputation is low.

I have tried doing following things:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1["_id"].reset_index(drop=True), pd.json_normalize(df1["winningTrans"])], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Also Tried:

```
def MarkWinnings(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if 'amount' in x.keys():
            return True
    return False
df1['Winnings'] =  df1['winningTrans'].apply(MarkWinnings)
```

Still I am getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys
```

Comment: Error is because you are applying a method to string values and in function you are doing `x.keys()` this is creating issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.join(df.winningTrans.apply(pd.Series))
```

Answer (score 1):

One line

```
df["winnings"] = df["a"].astype(str).str.contains('amount')
```

Error in your code
You should use `in` operator like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [{"amount": 2000, "hell": True}, {"hell": True}]})
def fun(x):
    return 'amount' in x
df["winnings"] = df["a"].apply(fun)
```

Comment: This Gives: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. If I fill NA with 0. I get TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable. I am very new to this and don't know enough.

Comment: what type of values are there in `winningTrans` column ? Current code is expecting it to be of type dict. If there are na values then fill na with `{}` empty dictionary

Comment: The one liner worked perfectly, and its better for further process. Thank You!

Comment: can you accept the answer and upvote it if you like

Comment: little shorter `def fun(x): return 'amount' in x` becuase `...in...` also gives `True/False`

Comment: @furas yes this will work perfectly.